# Private constructor and inheritance (Java)

Tags: java

I have first class for which constructor takes a parameter.

```
public class First {
    First(Object o){
        o.toString();
    }
}
```

I have a second class which extends this first one.

```
public class Second extends First {
    Second(Object o) {
        super(o);
    }
}
```

What I want is to keep the constructor of `Second` class private in order **to have a possibility to instantiate the only one instance of this class** (using Singleton pattern, for instance), but compiler doesn't allow me to do that.

If I can't set the constructor as private here, what can I do to allow the only one instance of the class to be created?

Comment: What exactly doesn't the compiler allow you to do? Simply making Second(Object o) private should work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the constructor of `Second` private with no problems. What you can't do is make the constructor of `First` private, unless you use nested classes.

As an example, this works fine:

```
class First {
    First(Object o) {
        o.toString();
    }
}

class Second extends First {
    private final static Second instance = new Second(new Object());

    private Second(Object o) {
        super(o);
    }

    public static Second getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is working !!

```
class First {
    First(Object o){
        o.toString();
    }

   public First() {//I think you missed this
   }
}
class Second extends First {
  private static Second obj ;
    private Second(Object o) {
        super(o);
  }

  private Second() {

  }

    public static Second getInstance(){
        if(obj == null){
            obj = new Second(new Object());
        }
        return obj;
    }


}
public class SingleTon {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Second sObj = Second.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Second extends First{
    private static final Second instance = new Second(new Object());
    private Second(Object o) {
    super(o);
    }
    public static Second instance(){
    return instance;
    }
}
```